# how to add user to AWS? adduser command not working

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Hello sorry I am very new to this.

I have a SSH to AWS instance running on Ubuntu; I'm trying to add users to be able to access the server without the key pair

I type '$ sudo adduser' at the command prompt and get this reply "adduser: Only one or two names allowed"

Any ideas on how to add a root user to the account?

Answer (score 2):

You will also need add following pieces of configs in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config at the bottom

Match User user_id1,user_id2,user_id3

PasswordAuthentication yes

Now reload ssh service.

This will activate password based authentications for these new users.

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html):

> If you are adding a user to an Ubuntu system, you should add the
>   --disabled-password option to avoid adding a password to the account.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo adduser newuser
```